# Excel button to send contents as email issue

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a form template that users fill out and email to a department to make a request, im using a mix of IF functions and conditional formatting so that the form hide/shows fields based on the user input.

My issue is that when the user pressed a button to email the form, the fields that have been shown (previously hidden) do not have table borders even though the show on the spreadsheet but not on the email.

I used code from a tutorial which i have linked below:
https://www.excell-en.com/auto-email-macro-excel

Here is how it is supposed to appear (as it shows in excel)
[Excel view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc44N.png)

And heres how it turns out in the email: [Email view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6r5L.png)

If possible I'd like to make the email look exactly how it shows in excel

Any ideas or help would be much appreciated

Comment: How are you showing or hiding the cells/fields?

Comment: @Bharat im using IF functions so that if a field has a certain entry then text will show, along with conditional formatting that if that text is shown then colour it and put a border around the cells

Comment: Can you please share one such condition and formatting, because the email works fine with whatever is visible in excel

Comment: @Bharat here is a link to download my sheet https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rD_lhLnoHAFAB1wP8iDGVsz3ZPcN_gVj/view?usp=sharing

The button is assigned on the Division Extensions sheet

Comment: I have requested access, please provide

Comment: @Bharat sorry i shouldve left it open, you can access now

Comment: I just applied the border format to those cells bottom cells and it works. Not sure if you change border formats using some other settings. Otherwise everything works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just reapplied the cell borders to those cells
[image]

And retriggered email and here is output

[image]

**EDIT**

After spending some time found out what's going wrong. The issue is with the conditional formatting. The VBA code creates an interim sheet and copies all the data and with conditional formatting. However, cells references are wrong as shown below
[image]

To make the cell reference correct, I started the rage with A1

```
    Set rng = Sheets("Division_Extensions").Range("A1:C20").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '
```

Now, the cell reference is correct so the conditional formatting works as it should
[image]

**Edit 2 : Add Subject reading data from a cell**

1. Add subject in some cell e.g. I added in sheet "Data Validation" 7th row and C cell
   [image]
2. Read the data from that cell and assign it in VBA code

   .subject = Sheets("Data Validation").Cells(7, 3)

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't fix this issue as if you were to change "sold-to" to "ship-to" the fields at the bottom change and it leaves behind the borders

Comment: Give me a moment, looking into it

Comment: What are you using to change  "sold-to" to "ship-to", I mean where is the logic of changing the content

Comment: The fields are using data validation to select them and the cells that show/hide have formula in them of IF statements, they should all be visible in the cells if you show formula  https://imgur.com/a/mFWi00E

Comment: Finally, it should work if you change the range :) It was very interesting to find

Comment: What range did you enter? did you just widen it?

Comment: Instead of B3, I Started with A1 in Sub AutoEmail(), probably at line number 63

Comment: Working for me as well now, cant believe i didnt try this. thanks for the help!

Comment: another quick thing, do you think its possible to make it so that the subject of the email pulls data from a specific cell within this code?

Comment: Yes quite possible I have edited the answer for that

Comment: One last thing (promise) i want to add a bit of text at the top of the email something like "please process the following:"

I tried adding .Body = "please process the following:" underneath .Subject line but it doesnt show in the email. any idea on that too?

Comment: Use .HTMLBody = "Please process the following:" & RangetoHTML(rng)

Comment: I am glad, I was useful :), got to learn something new too